# Steps to display clientSide Time on contentpage asp.net / c#

Tags: javascript, client-side-scripting

My master page has
 text box : txt1
 contentplaceholder= holder1

my content page 
 has a textbox : txt2

when I display the content page, it has to display the client side time (not the server time) automatically without any click events.
txt2.text ==> dd MMM format (eg : 31 May)

i found the following code :

```
    <input type="hidden" id="clienttime" runat="server" /> 
    (function $ {
         $("#clienttime").val(new Date().toUTCString()); 
    });
```

but, its not working and i am not sure about how to call this function and where to insert the code exactly. Please explain in step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
<input type="hidden" id="clienttime" runat="server" /> 
<script>
    $("#clienttime").val(new Date().toUTCString()); 
</script>
```

BUT, this puts the time in a hidden field so it can't be seen.

If it should be seen, change the hidden input to a label or normal textbox.

```
<label id="lblClientTime"></label>
<script>
    $("#lblClientTime").text(new Date().toUTCString());
</script>
```

Requires jQuery.

Comment: Then we don't have enough info. Please your entire master page and aspx page.

Comment: oh yeah...thank you so much @wazz ...now its working :)

Comment: Right on. You can use an html textbox without `runat="server"` --> `<input id="txtClientTime" type="text" />` script: `$("#txtClientTime").val(new Date().toUTCString());`.

Comment: if i want to access that textbox value inside my c# code, can i use the runat=server ...will that affect the time displayed?

Comment: No. Use runat=server.